# open port for memcached in network

Tags: linux, port

I want to share my `memcached` instance in my network. What is the best way to do this to give the network access to it?
How I open the port for it? Is there some easy way?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not advisable to allow networked access to memcached as it doesn't have any form of access control. `/etc/memcached.conf` on Ubuntu has this notice:

```
# Specify which IP address to listen on. The default is to listen on all IP addresses
# This parameter is one of the only security measures that memcached has, so make sure
# it's listening on a firewalled interface.
-l 127.0.0.1
```

If security is not a concern, then just comment out the `-l 127.0.0.1` line and restart memcached. That should permit network access.

In Red Hat-based distros, the configuration is stored in `/etc/sysconfig/memcached` instead, in which case you just have to remove `-l 127.0.0.1` from `OPTIONS`, if present.